# Insert a newline character into a categorical axis factor label in BokehJS

Tags: bokeh

I have a BokehJS plot with a categorical x-axis with factors that have strings that are very long. The label is being cut off by the edge of the graph and I would like to be able to insert a newline character either manually or automatically to produce a short length string (since it is now taller but narrower with a new line in the middle). I have tried the following code but it does not seem to create a change in the appearance.

```
p.x_range.attributes['factors'][0] = 'Some very long text string\nthat has now been cut'
```

Answer (score 2):

Until Bokeh adds either CSS rendering for xaxis ticks or add support for new line characters. Here's a workaround that can do what you are asking for, but it isn't perfect.

Instead of using a factor range, we can plot the data like normal using a placeholder x value. Then, we can place Labels under the y_axis at those placeholder positions which can then be rendered by css which will correctly print the newline.

---

Here's a working example using the Bokeh server.

*main.py*

```
from bokeh.plotting import ColumnDataSource, figure
from bokeh.models import LabelSet, FixedTicker
from bokeh.io import curdoc, show


factors = ["Some very long text string\nthat has now been cut\na",
           "Some very long text string\nthat has now been cut\nb"]
y = [50, 40]

# arbitrary placeholders which depends on the length and number of strings
x = [0, 2]
x_label = [0.65, 2.65]  # This is offset is based on the length of the string
y_label = [-2, -2]  # offset under the plot

source = ColumnDataSource(
    data=dict(factors=factors, x=x, y=y, x_label=x_label, y_label=y_label))

p = figure(x_range=(-1, 3), y_range=(0, 52))

p.circle(x='x', y='y', size=15, fill_color="orange", source=source)
p.xaxis.ticker = FixedTicker(ticks=x)

p.xaxis.major_label_text_font_size = '0pt'  # turn off x-axis tick labels
# p.xaxis.major_tick_line_color = None  # turn off x-axis major ticks
p.xaxis.minor_tick_line_color = None  # turn off x-axis minor ticks

labels = LabelSet(x='x_label', y='y_label', text='factors', source=source,
                  level='overlay', render_mode='css', text_align='center')

p.add_layout(labels)

curdoc().add_root(p)
```

*styles.css*

```
.bk-annotation-child {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    text-align: center;
}
```

---

The main disadvantage of this method is that the x_labels must be manually offset on the x axis from our placeholder x values. This is because the built-in bokeh centering called from the `LabelSet` is calculated on the full length string and not the not the longest sub string between `\n`. I'm sure you could tinker with this answer and programmatically determine the correct offset for an arbitrary string instead of eyeballing it as I did.

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful and detailed answer. In my case I am working with the BohekJS library rather that producing python code to serialize to JSON to render via BokehJS. I think I could convert the code but you do point out some issues in this approach. Thanks.

Comment: @David Apologies for misunderstanding your question as it is in pure BokehJS which I am not very well versed in. If my python answer helps you find a solution feel free to post it and I'll remove mine.

Comment: I would think the answer would still be helpful to others since most people are staying with Python and this question might come up in that context as well. Perhaps reposting a new question and providing your answer, after I figure out a solution would be the best course.

Comment: Hello, I just wanted to point to this method of inserting/overiding CSS from the python side. @rocheseb demonstrated the method here https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/6948